# Python Module can't be accessed when using venv

Tags: python, module, pip, python-3.8, python-venv

I love organization.

So I wanted to use venv to make sure group of modules be installed in a single venv. But when I install the package using pip inside a venv, the Python interpreter is not identifying that module. I have already included the environment site package folder to PATH variable.

How do I use python modules inside a venv?

#### Info

```
Code Editor : Sublime Text 3
Python version : 3.8.6 32bit
Package name which causes this problem : (Any Package)
```

#### Commands used :

```
python -m venv virenv
virenv\Scripts\activate
pip3 install package
```

#### The Code :

```py
import package
print("Hello")
```

#### The output

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'package'
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Ensure ```python``` is the same python as ```python3```.

Comment: How do you run your program?

Comment: The Sublime Text 3 has a shortcut key, which is 'ctrl+b'

Comment: what is the version of ```python``` in the virtualenv?

Comment: @ewong Sorry, I can't understand what you're asking. Sorry...

Comment: @Super Byte try running the program through the command line (`python script.py`)?

Comment: what's the output of these commands `pip3 list` and `(virenv) pip3 list` ?